# How can I have a subpicture in a tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is a problem that's come up from time to time as an aspect of a question, and it's something that I think would be an extremely useful addition to the TikZ/PGF system.

The basic set-up is to be able to designate a part of a tikzpicture as a "sub picture".  The ideal would be that it act a bit like a node with a tikzpicture as its contents, but without actually nesting tikzpictures (which, in my experience, causes a few issues with inheritance).  In particular, it should be possible to position the sub-picture according to its bounding box (just like with a node), and there should be a surrounding (rectangular) node with all its anchors (that's probably the easy part).

I can think of a few ways to do this, but others may have already solved this or have better ideas than me.

Comment: I had basically the same idea a while back. I also needed a sub-picture where I can still access the anchors from within the parent picture. Kind of turning the sub picture into a shape. Unfortunately, I never figured out how to do it.

Comment: Any reason why you can't just have two separate TikZ pictures with `remember picture` and `overlay` where applicable? You can get the bounding box by setting coordinates in places where you want the anchors in the sub-picture using the `current bounding box` node. These can then be referenced from the containing picture.

Comment: Just a note that this question has dated somewhat; the concept of a 'subpicture' is quite similar to that of a 'pic', and the question of positioning a 'pic' has been asked elsewhere, with a tikzmark solution now available, as introduced at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611460/86

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using just an external TikZ picture is not quite enough. If you want the position of the sub-picture to be influenced by elements from the containing picture and yet other elements from the containing picture be influenced by the sub-picture in turn, you need something additional. We could put our sub-picture in a `savebox` and use it inside of the main picture. We then use it inside of the main picture, by putting it inside of a node with `inner sep=0pt`. This allows us to position the node like any other node, while it can contain a TikZ picture that does not suffer from inheritance issues. If we additionally set the `remember picture` option on both pictures, we can references nodes within the first picture as well. We won't need the `overlay` option here, since it is basically one picture that happens to have a box in it. The following is a very basic example that demonstrates the concept:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \newsavebox\mysubpic
  \sbox{\mysubpic}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] %sub-picture
      \path[draw, fill=blue!30] (0,0) -- (2,2) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
      \path[draw, fill=green!30] (0,0) -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- cycle;
      \coordinate (orig) at (0,0);
      \coordinate (sw) at (current bounding box.south west);
      \coordinate (nw) at (current bounding box.north west);
      \coordinate (se) at (current bounding box.south east);
      \coordinate (ne) at (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}% needed, otherwise anchors are wrong!
  }
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \path[draw] node (a) {before} ++(2,0) node[inner sep=0pt] (subpic) {\usebox{\mysubpic}} ++(\wd\mysubpic,0) node {after};
    \foreach \anch in {south west, north west, south east, north east}{
      \fill[blue] (subpic.\anch) circle[radius=2pt];
    }
    \foreach \anch in {sw,nw,se,ne}{
      \fill (\anch) circle[radius=1pt];
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the resulting image:

[image: sub-picture in TikZ]

Comment: I've reimplemented the code we were having difficulty with using this new `savebox` approach, but unfortunately exactly the same issue arises. I've posted the problematic code in the chat room.

Comment: The context of the above comment is the discussion Andrew Stacey and I were having [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/409/from-answers-to-packages), about his new `knots` package.

Comment: The issues is not with the approach, it was with the engine used. This should work fine, as long as its used with `pdflatex`.