# Anchoring TiKZ pics

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

Is it possible to anchor a `TiKZ-pic` on an internal anchor?

I know (more or less) how to use `TiKZ pics` and know that they are draw arround their origin. What I would like to be sure is that it's not possible to use another internal coordinate as origin.

As an example consider next code.

```
\tikzset{
    mytest/.pic = {
         \node  (-A) at (0,0) {A};
         \node  (-B) at (0,1) {B};
             \node[fit=(-A) (-B),draw] (-C) {};
    }
}
```

It defines a pic with three nodes: `A`, `B` and `C` being `A.center` the `pic` origin. A command like

```
\draw pic (T) at (2,1) {mytest};
```

draws the pic with `A.center` at `(2,1)`.

Now, I would like to draw this `pic` but selecting `B.center` (or any other internal anchor like `C.120`) as anchoring (pic-origin) point. Is it possible?

In case you needed, there is some complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\tikzset{
    mytest/.pic = {
         \node  (-A) at (0,0) {A};
         \node  (-B) at (0,1) {B};
             \node[fit=(-A) (-B),draw] (-C) {};
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[blue!20] (0,0) grid (3,3);

\draw pic (S) at (0,0) {mytest};

\draw pic (T) at (2,1) {mytest};

\draw (S-A.north) to [out=90,in=-90] (T-B.south);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Question updates:

- I would like a general solution. For this particular case I know that node `B.center` is `1cm` above `A.center` and it's easy to shift the whole picture, but it's more difficult to shitf it if the origin must be at `C.120` or `C.100-|B.35`. Consider also some `pic` with variable size nodes.
- The example is just an example. I'm not trying to solve a particular problem. The question is more ... conceptual(?).
- The answer could be `no, it's not possible`. But, please, with some explanation as I always ask to my students ;-)

Comment: What about scoping the `pic` code with a `shift` option?

Comment: How "dynamic" are your anchors?  As far as I'm aware, the way to do this is to internally `shift` the whole `pic` so that a given point is now at `(0,0)` (in the `pic`s coordinate system).  But doing this involved knowing at the start of the `pic` where the desired anchor point is going to be.  Is that easily computable in your use-cases (as it is in your example)?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Imagin a `pic` with not fixed dimensions, can I also `shift` it? I've updated the question.

Comment: @LoopSpace My user-case doesn't exist but the first time I thought about it was trying to replace avoid using a `pgfnewshape` and using a `pic`.

Comment: @Ignasi: I posted as answer what I was proposing. If this is what you are looking for, I can add more details.

Comment: I would say that the answer is "Yes, with caveats".  Take a look at the latest version of the TQFT package.  That was rewritten with `pic`s instead of `node`s and has the facility to position relative to an "anchor", but the shift computation has to be done "by hand" rather than by PGF.  So if you can code it, you can shift it.

Comment: Having said that, the `node` anchor system isn't really any more sophisticated.  So as a general rule I would say "If you could do it with nodes, you can redo it with pics, but perhaps not as prettily".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Apparently, the idea of scoping the relevant code in `pic`s works.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\tikzset{pic shift/.store in=\shiftcoord,
    pic shift={(0,0)},
    mytest/.pic = {
             \begin{scope}[shift={\shiftcoord}]
         \node  (-A) at (0,0) {A};
         \node  (-B) at (0,1) {B};
             \node[fit=(-A) (-B),draw] (-C) {};
         \end{scope}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[blue!20] (0,0) grid (3,3);

\draw pic (S) at (0,0) {mytest};

\draw pic (T) at (2,1) {mytest};

\draw (S-A.north) to [out=90,in=-90] (T-B.south);

\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[blue!20] (0,0) grid (3,3);

\draw[pic shift={(1,1)}] pic (S) at (0,0) {mytest};

\draw pic (T) at (2,1) {mytest};

\draw (S-A.north) to [out=90,in=-90] (T-B.south);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result without shifts:

[image]

while shifting the first pic (S):

[image]

> **EDIT**

*Trying to answer to [last Ignasi's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185279/anchoring-tikz-pics#comment428375_185283): Can I still use your code to place any internal pic coordinate on a desired place?*

Probably, the answer is: *yes, to some extent*. Meaning that in a tikzpicture, while referring to a pic, you are actually taking into account his origin, namely whatever is placed in the coordinate `(0,0)`. In the current case, node `A`. So, you can shift the complete pic with respect to this point, but I suspect you can not *place any internal pic coordinate on a desired place*. You can place any pic coordinate on a desired place as a consequence of having shifted the pic with respect to its origin.

Let us consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}

% code by Andrew:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33765/13304
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{pic shift/.store in=\shiftcoord,
    pic shift={(0,0)},
    pic-a min height/.store in=\picaminheight,
    pic-a min height=0pt,
    pic-a min width/.store in=\picaminwidth,
    pic-a min width=0pt,
    mytest/.pic = {
         \begin{scope}[shift={\shiftcoord}]
         \node[minimum height=\picaminheight,
               minimum width=\picaminwidth,
               draw]  (-A) at (0,0) {A};
         \node  (-B) at (0,1) {B};
             \node[fit=(-A) (-B),draw] (-C) {};
         \end{scope}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[blue!20] (0,0) grid (3,3);

\draw[pic-a min height=1cm,
 pic-a min width=1cm,
 pic shift={(1,1)}] pic (S) at (0,0) {mytest} node[coordinate] (sn){};

\gettikzxy{(S-C.east)}{\sbx}{\sby}

\draw[red,pic shift={(\sbx,\sby)}] pic (T) at (0,0) {mytest};

\gettikzxy{(S-C.south)}{\sdx}{\sdy}
\draw[blue,pic shift={(\sdx,\sdy)}] pic (T) at (0,0) {mytest};

\gettikzxy{(S-C.east)}{\sex}{\sey}
\draw[pic-a min width=0cm,green!75!black,pic shift={(\sex,\sey)}] pic (O) at (1,0) {mytest};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which leads to:

[image]

Recalling that the origin of `mytest` is node `-A`, we have the first pic (S) with increased size denoted in black. It will be our reference.

Thanks to Andrew's `\gettikzxy`, we can grab coordinates of (S-C.east). The second `mytest` pic (T), in red, is placed in position `(0,0)` (of the general tikzpicture) and we operate a shift into (S-C.east) coordinates. As expected, (T-A) is put in `(S-C.east)`. The same happens for pic `M`. However, apparently it is not possible to anchor pics with respect to their C node points. What you can do, is to take advantage of both `pic shift` and coordinate placement for anchoring a pic with respect to his C node (I admit, is not that elegant). For example the green (O) `mytest` pic is anchored with respect to his `-C.south east` point in (1,3).

Comment: Thanks for the code. It's nice but I'm not sure if it solves all problems. Can I use it to place `C.south west` (from a third pic) on `right=2cm and 3mm of S-A.30`?

Comment: @Ignasi: you're welcome! I'm not sure to understand 100% the question. Are you looking for a way to place only part of your pic (C node fitting A and B)? In the answer, shifting operation always need a pair of coordinates, namely you can't set `pic shift={(S-A.north)}` because, you know, a pic prefixes his name.

Comment: Let me try again. How can I use your code to place a complete `pic` with its internal `-C.30` anchor on `(2,3)`? More complex, imagin a `pic` with args which modifiy `A` (or `B`) width and height, `C` will vary accordingly and I don't know exact dimensions. Can I still use your code to place any internal `pic` coordinate on a desired place?

Comment: @Ignasi: I investigated a bit, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you again for your effort. I'll need some time to understand it but I think it doesn't solve my `intended` question. Although I admit that my `written` question could be different from my `intended` one. That's the problem when someone tries to express ideas in a non mother tongue. I'll study your code and if I need more help will make a follow-up question.

Comment: @Ignasi: I see your point (not being english speaker, and writer, as well). Please, consider there might be the possibility that someone shows up saying everything is simpler. It was a pleasure to do this investigation as I'm planning to use `pic`s in sa-tikz to draw Cantor architectures (starting from Benes ones).

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to this problem for quite a while now and still didnt find a solution. Did still no one find it? Being able to shift by a a-priori known coordinate is helpful but not enough in most cases...

Comment: I think it's a little ridiculous but you could draw a phantom pic and then shift your real pic based on a distance calculation in the phantom pic. That way you can shift according to an internal anchor.

Comment: @tsj: not sure if that would work, but you are definitely welcome to try it out and eventually post your own solution.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a `tikzmark` solution.  The point of `tikzmark` is that it writes the location of a position on the page to the `aux` file so that it can be read in on the next compilation.  So to figure out where to locate the `pic`, we write out the location of the desired anchor and then on the next compilation we use that to shift the `pic`.

Of course, this then shifts the pic and so the location of the anchor point.  But actually what we want is the relative displacement of the anchor point from the pic's origin and that doesn't change so we write both the origin and anchor point.

This does mean that the shift code has to be included in the pic code.  If you have complete control over the pic code then this is easy.  If not, you can wrap the existing pic in a new one with the shift code.

Now, I figured that this was quite a useful thing to be able to do so I've added it to the latest version of `tikzmark` which is (at time of writing - I'll update this when it gets uploaded to CTAN) available from [github](https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark) (download `tikzmark.dtx` and run `tex tikzmark.dtx`).

Here's an example of it with your code.  The red dots are the points where the pics are located.  Note that the pic anchor is specified in *internal coordinates*, so if there is a pic name then it isn't used.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185279/86}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,tikzmark}

\tikzset{
  mytest/.pic = {
    \begin{scope}[adjust pic position]
    \node  (-A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node  (-B) at (0,1) {B};
    \node[fit=(-A) (-B),draw] (-C) {};
    \end{scope}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[blue!20] (0,0) grid (3,3);

\fill[red] (0,0) circle[radius=3pt];
\fill[red] (2,1) circle[radius=3pt];

\draw[pic anchor=(-B.center)] pic (S) at (0,0) {mytest};

\draw[pic anchor=(-C.120)] pic (T) at (2,1) {mytest};

\draw (S-A.north) to [out=90,in=-90] (T-B.south);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Relocating pics]

Comment: Just to note that I'm experimenting with the exact syntax of this for inclusion in the `tikzmark` library.  Please check the documentation for whatever version of tikzmark you have for the correct syntax to use.

Answer (score 5):

As though Claudio has given a complete answer, I think there's a simpler one, which may be either a bug or an undocumented feature of Ti*k*Z (because it's not in the Manual). It's not a complete answer because you cannot use *all* internal coordinates of the `pic` but rather just the coordinates from the node placed at the origin.

Out of curiosity I tried to put a node at the `pic`'s origin and access its anchors through the `pic` command, and guess what? It works. So, apperantly just make a `pic` with a node as bounding box and you can place it with respect to its anchors!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\tikzset{mytest/.pic = {\node[draw, minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=.5cm] (-box) at (0,0) {};
                   \node[above] (-A) at (-box.south) {A};
                   \node[below] (-B) at (-box.north) {B};}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[blue!20] (0,0) grid (3,3);

\draw pic[anchor=south west] (S) at (0,0) {mytest};

\draw pic[below left=1mm] (T) at (2,2) {mytest};

\draw (S-A.north) to [out=90,in=-90] (T-B.south);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's what happens here. Instead, with `\draw pic[anchor=south west] {mytest};` the pic code inherits the `anchor=south west` so the `-box` node is anchored south west. It works here but if you draw another node in the pic it will also be anchored south west. A solution would be to reset `anchor` after making the first node.

Comment: I don't think I understood you correctly. However, the main idea here is to have a bounding box node, one that would act as the `pic`s anchor points. Perhaps if you could share an example where this fails I'd be glad to see it!

Answer (score 4):

This extends the answer of [Claudio Fiandrino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185283/93369) which uses the `\gettikzxy` by Andrew.

I missed the possibility of anchoring a `pic` with ***any*** internal coordinate, at some other `pic` internal coordinate. E.g. placing the lower left corner of my `pic` in the middle of the diamond of another `pic`.

**New solution:**

This is done using my new coommand `\placePic`:

```
\placePic{<new pic name>}
         {<placement coord.>}
         {<pic type>}
         {<anchor, internal coord. extension>}
         {<pic actions>}
```

It requires that:

- The internal coordinates are defined before drawing
- The internal coordinates to be defined within the scope which shifts the `pic`

The drawing must be done within

```
\ifnum\drawit = 1
    % Drawing of the pic
\fi
```

As with this `pic`:

[image: Example pic]

```
placement square/.pic=
{

    \def\sideLen{4mm}
    \def\flapLen{0.7mm}
    \def\fillPercentage{0.8}
    \def\cornerMarkLen{1mm}

    \begin{scope}[thick, shift={\shiftcoord}, xscale=\xscaling, yscale=\yscaling]
        
        % Coordinates must be inside of scope which does the shifting.
        % All coordinates must be defined before drawing
        \coordinate (-center) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (-left) at (-\sideLen/2-\flapLen,0);
        \coordinate (-upper) at (0,\sideLen/2+\flapLen);
        \coordinate (-right) at (\sideLen/2+\flapLen,0);
        \coordinate (-lower) at (0,-\sideLen/2-\flapLen);
        \coordinate (-upper left) at (-\sideLen/2,\sideLen/2);
        \coordinate (-upper right) at (\sideLen/2,\sideLen/2);
        \coordinate (-lower left) at (-\sideLen/2,-\sideLen/2);
        \coordinate (-lower right) at (\sideLen/2,-\sideLen/2);
        
        % The drawing
        \ifnum\drawit = 1
            % Rectangle
            \draw[pic actions] (-\sideLen/2,-\sideLen/2) rectangle +(\sideLen,\sideLen);
            \fill[pic actions, very thin, opacity=0.2] (-\sideLen/2*\fillPercentage,-\sideLen/2*\fillPercentage) 
                rectangle +(\sideLen*\fillPercentage,\sideLen*\fillPercentage);
            % Cross
            \draw[pic actions] (-center.center)
                edge (-left)
                edge (-upper)
                edge (-right)
                edge (-lower);

            \node[opacity=1] at (-center) {a};

            % Orientation mark at corner
            \draw[pic actions, green!80!black, opacity=1] ([yshift=\cornerMarkLen]-lower right.center)
                -- (-lower right.center)
                -- +(-\cornerMarkLen,0);
        \fi

    \end{scope}
}
```

Here with a whole example, showing its benefits:

[image: Whole example]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}


% code by Andrew:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33765/13304
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother

% #1 = name of new placement
% #2 = where to place (e.g. myA-star)
% #3 = pic type
% #4 = internal node to use as anchor (eg. -left point)
% #5 = pic actions (other settings than color e.g. xshift, opacity, ...)
\newcommand{\placePic}[5]
{
    \path pic[draw it=0] (#1-PATH) at (0,0) {#3};
    \gettikzxy{(#1-PATH#4)}{\sdx}{\sdy}
    \gettikzxy{#2}{\sbx}{\sby}
    \def\newX{\sbx - \sdx}
    \def\newY{\sby - \sdy}
    \path [draw it=1, pic shift={(\newX,\newY)}] pic[#5] (#1) at (0,0) {#3};
}

\tikzset
{
    % Relative positioning variables
    pic shift/.store in=\shiftcoord,
    pic shift={(0,0)},
    draw it/.store in=\drawit,
    draw it=1,
    xscaling/.store in=\xscaling,
    xscaling=1,
    yscaling/.store in=\yscaling,
    yscaling=1,
    %
    base rectangle/.pic=
    {
        \begin{scope}[shift={\shiftcoord}]
            \draw[very thick,pic actions] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
            \node[draw,circle,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0,thick,pic actions] (-circle) at (.5,.5) {};
            \node[draw,rectangle,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0,thick,pic actions] (-square) at (.5,1.5) {};
            \node[draw,diamond,minimum size=2.5mm,inner sep=0,thick,pic actions] (-diamond) at (1.5,1.5) {};
            \node[draw,star,minimum size=2.5mm,inner sep=0,thick,pic actions] (-star) at (1.5,.5) {};
        \end{scope}
    },
    placement square/.pic=
    {

        \def\sideLen{4mm}
        \def\flapLen{0.7mm}
        \def\fillPercentage{0.8}
        \def\cornerMarkLen{1mm}

        \begin{scope}[thick, shift={\shiftcoord}, xscale=\xscaling, yscale=\yscaling]
            
            % Coordinates must be inside of scope which does the shifting. That is "shift={\shiftcoord}"
            % All coordinates must be defined before drawing
            \coordinate (-center) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (-left) at (-\sideLen/2-\flapLen,0);
            \coordinate (-upper) at (0,\sideLen/2+\flapLen);
            \coordinate (-right) at (\sideLen/2+\flapLen,0);
            \coordinate (-lower) at (0,-\sideLen/2-\flapLen);
            \coordinate (-upper left) at (-\sideLen/2,\sideLen/2);
            \coordinate (-upper right) at (\sideLen/2,\sideLen/2);
            \coordinate (-lower left) at (-\sideLen/2,-\sideLen/2);
            \coordinate (-lower right) at (\sideLen/2,-\sideLen/2);
            
            % The drawing
            \ifnum\drawit = 1
                % Rectangle
                \draw[pic actions] (-\sideLen/2,-\sideLen/2) rectangle +(\sideLen,\sideLen);
                \fill[pic actions, very thin, opacity=0.2] (-\sideLen/2*\fillPercentage,-\sideLen/2*\fillPercentage) 
                    rectangle +(\sideLen*\fillPercentage,\sideLen*\fillPercentage);
                % Cross
                \draw[pic actions] (-center.center)
                    edge (-left)
                    edge (-upper)
                    edge (-right)
                    edge (-lower);

                \node[opacity=1] at (-center) {a};

                % Orientation mark at corner
                \draw[pic actions, green!80!black, opacity=1] ([yshift=\cornerMarkLen]-lower right.center)
                    -- (-lower right.center)
                    -- +(-\cornerMarkLen,0);
            \fi

        \end{scope}
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Help lines (grid)
    \draw[help lines,ultra thin,step=5mm] (-.5,-.5) grid (2.5,2.5);
    \draw[help lines,thin,step=10mm] (-.5,-.5) grid (2.5,2.5);

    \pic[black] (base) at (0,0) {base rectangle};

    % #1 = name of new placement
    % #2 = where to place (e.g. myA-star)
    % #3 = pic type
    % #4 = internal node to use as anchor (eg. -left point)
    % #5 = pic actions (other settings than color e.g. xshift, opacity, ...)
    \placePic{red square}
             {(base-circle)}{placement square}{-lower}
             {red, opacity=0.5}
    \placePic{cyan square}
             {(base-star)}{placement square}{-right}
             {cyan, opacity=0.5}
    \placePic{blue square}
             {(base-diamond)}{placement square}{-lower left}
             {blue, opacity=0.5,yscaling=-1}
    \placePic{orange square}
             {(base-square)}{placement square}{-left}
             {orange, opacity=0.5, xshift=2mm, xscaling=-1}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Original solution:**

**Note: I have realised that this comes with some flaws as other commands such as** `\fill`, `edge`, `\node` **will require additional commands which will limit what the** `pic` **can draw. See updated answer above.**

This is done using my new coommand `\placePic`:

```
\placePic{<new pic name>}
         {<placement coord.>}
         {<pic type>}
         {<anchor, internal coord. extension>}
         {<pic actions>}
```

It is required that the `pic` to place is not drawn automatically, it should require the `draw` option. That is; the `pic` should not be created with e.g. `\draw` but instead with `\path` without the `draw` option. See e.g.:

```
placement square/.pic=
{
    \begin{scope}[shift={\shiftcoord},thick]
        \def\sideLen{4mm}

        \path[pic actions] (-\sideLen/2,-\sideLen/2) rectangle +(\sideLen,\sideLen);
        \path[pic actions] (-\sideLen/2,0) -- +(-0.7mm,0) coordinate (-left point);
        \path[pic actions] (\sideLen/2,0) -- +(0.7mm,0) coordinate (-right point);
        \path[pic actions] (0,\sideLen/2) -- +(0,0.7mm) coordinate (-upper point);
        \path[pic actions] (0,-\sideLen/2) -- +(0,-0.7mm) coordinate (-lower point);

        \coordinate (-upper left) at (-\sideLen/2,\sideLen/2);
        \coordinate (-upper right) at (\sideLen/2,\sideLen/2);
        \coordinate (-lower left) at (-\sideLen/2,-\sideLen/2);
        \coordinate (-lower right) at (\sideLen/2,-\sideLen/2);
    \end{scope}
}
```

This is done with the cost of creating the paths two times. There is for certain some more efficient way of doing this, but I searched a lot without any success.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

% code by Andrew:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33765/13304
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother

% #1 = name of new placement
% #2 = where to place (e.g. myA-star)
% #3 = pic type
% #4 = internal node to anchor (eg. -left point)
% #5 = pic actions
\newcommand{\placePic}[5]
{
    \path pic (#1-PATH) at (0,0) {#3};
    \gettikzxy{(#1-PATH#4)}{\sdx}{\sdy}
    \gettikzxy{#2}{\sbx}{\sby}
    \def\newX{\sbx - \sdx}
    \def\newY{\sby - \sdy}
    \path [pic shift={(\newX,\newY)}] pic[draw,#5] (#1) at (0,0) {#3};
}

\tikzset
{
    pic shift/.store in=\shiftcoord,
    pic shift={(0,0)},
    base rectangle/.pic=
    {
        \begin{scope}[shift={\shiftcoord}]
            \draw[very thick,pic actions] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
            \node[draw,circle,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0,thick,pic actions] (-circle) at (.5,.5) {};
            \node[draw,rectangle,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0,thick,pic actions] (-square) at (.5,1.5) {};
            \node[draw,diamond,minimum size=2.5mm,inner sep=0,thick,pic actions] (-diamond) at (1.5,1.5) {};
            \node[draw,star,minimum size=2.5mm,inner sep=0,thick,pic actions] (-star) at (1.5,.5) {};
        \end{scope}
    },
    placement square/.pic=
    {
        \begin{scope}[shift={\shiftcoord},thick]
            \def\sideLen{4mm}
            \path[pic actions] (-\sideLen/2,-\sideLen/2) rectangle +(\sideLen,\sideLen);
            \path[pic actions] (-\sideLen/2,0) -- +(-0.7mm,0) coordinate (-left point);
            \path[pic actions] (\sideLen/2,0) -- +(0.7mm,0) coordinate (-right point);
            \path[pic actions] (0,\sideLen/2) -- +(0,0.7mm) coordinate (-upper point);
            \path[pic actions] (0,-\sideLen/2) -- +(0,-0.7mm) coordinate (-lower point);
            \coordinate (-upper left) at (-\sideLen/2,\sideLen/2);
            \coordinate (-upper right) at (\sideLen/2,\sideLen/2);
            \coordinate (-lower left) at (-\sideLen/2,-\sideLen/2);
            \coordinate (-lower right) at (\sideLen/2,-\sideLen/2);
        \end{scope}
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Help lines (grid)
    \draw[help lines,ultra thin,step=5mm] (-.5,-.5) grid (2.5,2.5);
    \draw[help lines,thin,step=10mm] (-.5,-.5) grid (2.5,2.5);

    \pic[black] (base) at (0,0) {base rectangle};

    % #1 = name of new placement
    % #2 = where to place (e.g. myA-star)
    % #3 = pic type
    % #4 = internal node to use as anchor (eg. -left point)
    % #5 = pic actions
    \placePic{red square}
             {(base-circle)}{placement square}{-lower point}
             {red, opacity=0.5}
    \placePic{blue square}
             {(base-diamond)}{placement square}{-lower left}
             {blue, opacity=0.5}
    \placePic{green square}
             {(base-star)}{placement square}{-right point}
             {green, opacity=0.5}
    \placePic{orange square}
             {(base-square)}{placement square}{-left point}
             {orange, opacity=0.5, xshift=2mm}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```