# In tikz, why does a pic with a tree get distorted upon positioning with e.g. `right=of`

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-pic

I'm trying to connect with edges tikz pics. I thought of using (sub)graphs like subgraph I_n and specifying the nodes with the V key, but I get an error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\tikz@lib@graph@typesetter ->\tikzgraphnodetext
```

So I then I thought of positioning the pics and connecting them with edges. I could specify their coordinates manually, that works, but if I use the positioning library, the pics get distorted and also aren't positioned as expected. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
  a/.style={code={
      \node [fill=red!20, shape=circle] {A}
      child{ node {B} }
      child{ node {B} }
      child{ node {B} };
    } }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic [local bounding box=A1] at (0,0) {a};
  \pic [right=of A1] {a};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Comment: Add `\draw (A1.south west) rectangle (A1.north east);` at the end to see it.

Comment: The positioning issue is straightforwardly explained as indicated: the A node of the second pic is right of the centre of the first one. However, the distortion is another matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a partial answer. It aims to do 2 things:

1. demonstrate how to adjust the vertical and horizontal positioning of the second `pic` appropriately;
2. clarify the issue concerning the distortion of the second tree.

By default, the second `pic` gets aligned with the *centre* of the first `pic`.

[image: default alignment]

The `A` node in each tree is centred on `(0,0)` relative to the `pic` because this is default for any node in a `pic` (or `tikzpicture`) and nothing has told TikZ to do differently. But the `right=of A1` means right of the *centre* of `A1`. Hence, the `(0,0)` position in the second `pic` is right of `A1.center`.

The easiest way to address this problem is to specify the anchors we'd prefer TikZ to use.

In the `pic`, we can say

```
\node [anchor=north] {A}
```

to align the top of the first node with `(0,0)` rather than the centre.

When aligning the second `pic`, we can then say

```
  \pic [right=of A1.north] {a tree};
```

to ensure the `(0,0)` is right of the top of the first `pic` rather than right of the centre.

[image: align at top]

That takes care of the vertical alignment. But it would obviously be better to align the second `pic` to the right of the top right corner of the first one, rather than the top centre. So we can substitute `north east` for `north` when aligning:

```
\pic [right=of A1.north east] {a tree};
```

[image: improved horizontal alignment]

This is still not sufficient, so we probably need to add some manual adjustment at this point. We can't tell TikZ to align the left of the second `pic` with the right of the first because the second one hasn't been constructed yet. So, instead we can nudge the second over a bit. Let's try nudging by `10pt`.

```
\pic [right=of A1.north east, xshift=10pt] {a tree};
```

[image: nudge to improve horizontal alignment]

And now the `pic`s are aligned pretty much as required and as well as we can probably manage.

However, none of this addresses the more difficult problem: the distortion of the *content* of the second `pic`.

Here's the output of the code with the above changes:

[image: pic-by-pic]

And here's the output when the trees are constructed with the same code without using a `pic`:

[image: tree-by-tree]

## EDIT

Thanks to [Torbjørn T.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28712654#28712654) for directing me to [A.Ellett's analysis and workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237580/) which identifies a problem involving node anchors inside `pic`s erroneously inheriting the effects of relative positioning used to place the `pic`. In effect, this means that every node in the second tree inherits the effects of `right=of A1.north east`. Although they don't all end up in the same spot, because later code within the `pic` overrides the placement, one effect lingers and that is that the default anchor is switched by `right=of...` from `.center` to `.west`. As [Torbjørn T. points out](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28712867#28712867), the `.west` anchor of the children is being aligned rather than their `.center` anchors, skewing them to the right (east).

[image: skew effect]

We can workaround this bug by reinstating the default `.center` anchor for nodes explicitly by adding `every node/.append style={anchor=center}` or similar to the scope within the `pic`.

```
\tikzset{%
  pics/a tree/.style={%
    code={%
      \begin{scope}[local bounding box=#1, every node/.append style={anchor=center}]% A.Ellett's workaround from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237580/, pointed out by Torbjørn T. in http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28712654#28712654, http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28712867#28712867
        \node [fill=red!20, shape=circle, anchor=north] {A}
        child{ node {B} }
        child{ node {B} }
        child{ node {B} };
      \end{scope}%
    }%
  },
}
```

Increasing our `nudge` a little to accommodate the de-skewing effect, we then get the following result for the two `pic`s.

[image: de-skewed trees]

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{% this code is used to show the effect of the inheritance bug 
  pics/a tree/.style={%
    code={%
      \begin{scope}[local bounding box=#1]
        \node [fill=red!20, shape=circle, anchor=north] {A}
        child{ node {B} }
        child{ node {B} }
        child{ node {B} };
      \end{scope}%
    }%
  },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}% an example demonstrating the bug
  \pic {a tree=A1};
  \pic [right=of A1.north east, xshift=20pt]  {a tree};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}% non-pic version for comparison
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=A1]
    \node [fill=red!20, shape=circle, anchor=north] {A}
    child{ node {B} }
    child{ node {B} }
    child{ node {B} };
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=A2]
    \node [fill=red!20, shape=circle, right=of A1.north east, anchor=north] {A}
    child{ node {B} }
    child{ node {B} }
    child{ node {B} };
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{% work around the problem
  pics/a tree/.style={%
    code={%
      \begin{scope}[local bounding box=#1, every node/.append style={anchor=center}]% A.Ellett's workaround from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237580/, pointed out by Torbjørn T. in http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28712654#28712654, http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28712867#28712867
        \node [fill=red!20, shape=circle, anchor=north] {A}
        child{ node {B} }
        child{ node {B} }
        child{ node {B} };
      \end{scope}%
    }%
  },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}% demonstrate workaround
  \pic {a tree=A1};
  \pic [right=of A1.north east, xshift=20pt]  {a tree};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, perfect would be a patch to fix the bug ;). But at least it seems to work!