# pgfdeclareshape cannot access the north, east, west, south anchors

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to declare a custom pgf shape. I have a problem that I cannot access the east, west, north, south anchors. This works:

```
\pgfdeclareshape{mixer}{%
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle]
  \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{east}
  \backgroundpath{%
    \pgf@x=\radius
    \pgf@y=\radius
    \centerpoint \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}{\radius}
  }
}
```

However, as soon as I try to use something like:

```
\northeast \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
```

or

```
\north \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
```

I get undefined command. Why is that?

Comment: because circle shape doesn't have those saved anchors. They are just anchors that are calculated upon call.

Comment: @percusse is there a way to access them from within \pgfdeclareshape?

Comment: No because they don't exist until they are called. You have to define them yourself if need be

Comment: @user110971 Suggestion: have you looked at Ti*k*Z `pic`s? They are kinda like shapes, but much more simple. Declaring new shapes are (I'd say) not for the end-user, but `pic`s are. You can set coordinates inside the `pic` which behave like node anchors... Maybe it's what you looking for: [check this link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185279/anchoring-tikz-pics).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still have a chance: the definition of those anchors are hidden in

```
\pgf@anchor@⟨shape name⟩@⟨anchor name⟩
```

So `\north` can be retrieved by

```
\pgf@anchor@mixer@north
```

## Full code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{mixer}{%
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle]
  \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{east}
  \backgroundpath{%
    \centerpoint
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}}{\radius}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgf@anchor@mixer@east}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgf@anchor@mixer@north}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgf@anchor@mixer@south}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgf@anchor@mixer@west}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  }
}

\tikz\node[mixer]{0123456789};

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I reference north east?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, at least not directly.  But you see, you can (1) retrieve the north anchor, (2) remember the y-coordinate, (3) retrieve the east anchor, (4) remember the x-coordinate, and (5) use x and y-coordinates as that of northeast anchor.

Comment: My pgf skills are not enough :-D Can you elaborate it in more detail?

Comment: For northeast:
(0) `\newdimen\matt@x \newdimen\matt@y` this declares new variables. 
(1)(2) `\pgf@anchor@mixer@north \matt@y\pgf@y` this remembers y coordinate.
(3)(4) `\pgf@anchor@mixer@east \matt@x\pgf@x` this remembers x coordinate. 
(5) `\pgfpathliineto{\pgfpoint{\matt@x}{\matt@y}}` this uses the x and y coordinates.