# TikZ: Hide pic while still calculating internal coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

**EDIT:**

Juan have a great approach when the coordinates can be know since before drawing the whole picture. But sometimes there are complex paths with relative positions which may require that the coordinates are created in the middle of the path.

**Original question:**

How may I hide or not show a `pic` but still have it calculate the internal coordinates/nodes?

Here I draw blue lines from the origin to every internal coordinate of the `pic`. My current solution is by having the command `opacity=0` for the scope of the picture:

[image: Drawn]

[image: Not drawn]

But it does not hold when any internal drawing of the `pic` has its opacity changed as it overrides the `opacity=0` command:

```
\fill[fill=yellow,opacity=0.5] (0,0) rectangle (-1,-1) coordinate (-point 2);
```

[image: Not drawn, opacity changed internally]

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset
{
    draw it/.store in=\drawit,
    draw it=1,
    random symbols/.pic=
    {
        \begin{scope}[opacity=\drawit]
            \draw (1,-1) -- +(0,1) coordinate (-point 1);
            \fill[fill=yellow] (0,0) rectangle (-1,-1) coordinate (-point 2);
            \node[draw,minimum size=1cm] (-point 3) at (-1,1) {a};
            \path (0,0)
                -- ++(1,1)
                edge[red] coordinate[pos=1] (-point 4) +(-1,0);
        \end{scope}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm]

    \path[draw it=1] pic (thepic) at (0,0) {random symbols};

    \draw[blue,very thick] (0,0)
        edge (thepic-point 1)
        edge (thepic-point 2)
        edge (thepic-point 3)
        edge (thepic-point 4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the original problem of remembering coordinates before they are defined, the tikzmark library can be used to write locations to the aux file that can be used on a subsequent run.  Would that help at all?

Comment: @AndrewStacey That might be something, could you provide an example as an answer?

Comment: @AndrewStacey Or point me in the right direction

Comment: I can do that.  What's the purpose in remembering these coordinates?  What are you using them for?  Did this come out of another question on this site that you can point me to?

Comment: @AndrewStacey Yes, it is about anchoring pics with their internal coordinates. I have searched a lot after an answer to the relevant question and thereby tried to find a solution myself. See my answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610872/93369

Comment: @AndrewStacey I updated my answer on the other question, which highlights some of the flaws of my previous answer.

Comment: Ah, I wondered if it might be.  I've bookmarked that question so that I can post a tikzmark answer.  It actually felt like a useful enough addition to meld into the tikzmark library itself so I've added it to the code on [`github`](https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark).  There's an example at https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark/blob/master/tests/piclocation.tex

Comment: @AndrewStacey I just tried to compile your Github example, but it did not work. It doesn't recognise the keys `wrap pic` and `pic anchor`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you use the version of tikzmark from github?  Download `tikzmark.dtx` and run `tex tikzmark.dtx` to generate the latest version of the library.

Comment: I've posted a tikzmark solution over at that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can define the coordinates in your `pic` code first and then draw the `pic` (or not) inside an `\ifnum` command.

Something like:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset
{
    draw it/.store in=\drawit,
    draw it=1,
    random symbols/.pic=
    {   % coordinates (and one node)
        \node[minimum size=1cm] (-aux) at (-1, 1) {};
        \coordinate (-point 1) at ( 1, 0);
        \coordinate (-point 2) at (-1,-1);
        \coordinate (-point 3) at (-aux.south east);
        \coordinate (-point 4) at ( 0, 1);
        % optional drawing
        \ifnum\drawit = 1
            \draw (1,-1) -- (-point 1);
            \fill[fill=yellow,opacity=0.5] (0,0) rectangle (-point 2);
            \node[draw,minimum size=1cm] at (-aux) {a};
            \path (0,0) -- (1,1) edge[red] (-point 4);
        \fi
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm]

\foreach\i in {0,1}
{
    \path pic[draw it=\i] (thepic\i) at (3*\i,0) {random symbols};

    \draw[blue,very thick] (3*\i,0)
        edge (thepic\i-point 1)
        edge (thepic\i-point 2)
        edge (thepic\i-point 3)
        edge (thepic\i-point 4);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces:
[image]

Comment: I thought about that approach too, but realised that some times there are complex paths which may require one to create the coordinates while creating the path. Specially when using relative coordinates.

Comment: @RobinHellmers in this case you can put the coordinates in a `\path[draw=none]... coordinate (-point 1) ...` and then draw or fill the desired lines or shapes inside the `\ifnum`. It requires to duplicate some code, which I don't like, but I don't know the real `pic` you need to draw

Comment: Yes that is an option. I tried to have a MWE and also keep the question general for others to have use of it in the future. It might not exist any other better option, but I would like to keep the question open for a while in case of another option.

Comment: As a side note, you probably know that you can save your paths and reuse them afterwards, which could be an improvement of the solution Juan provided.

Comment: @SebGlav I'm actually not sure how to do that. Could you expand on that?

Comment: @RobinHellmers My `spath3` TikZ library can be used for saving and restoring paths.