# TikZ: position a pic with its inner coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment, tikz-node, tikz-pic

In the [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) below, I made a TikZ pic called `bus` with one argument. The argument creates nodes within the pic that will be used as connection points to other buses. I would like to align these pics by their connection points, i.e., the nodes within them. So in the picture below, the 1 on the right should be in-line with the 2 on the left (vertically centered). But I would love the flexibility of aligning that 1 on the right bus with 1, 2, or 3 on the left bus.

Is this possible? The code I tried failed I think, because the position command to pic defines the origin that the pic is made from, so there isn't any coordinate b-1 in the pic at that time. This is a very simple example, and while I'm not married to using pics, the prospect of using them for this sort of thing is enticing to make building blocks for complex diagrams.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\def\busnodespace{3mm}
\tikzset{
pics/bus/.style n args={1}{
        code = { %
            \draw[ultra thick] (0, {-0.75*\busnodespace}) -- (0, {(#1-1+0.75)*\busnodespace});
            \foreach \y in {1,...,#1} {\node[inner sep=0pt] (-\y) at (0.0,{(\y-1)*\busnodespace}) {\color{red}{\scriptsize\y}};}
        }}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic (a) at (0,0) {bus=3}; % bus of size 3
%    \pic (b) at (2,0) {bus=1}; % bus of size 1 -- is it possible to position this (elegantly, hopefully with no math)
                                % so coordinate b1 is in line with a2?
                               % ie I would like a flat line
%    \pic[right=of a-2] (b) {bus=1};  % obv this wont cut
    \pic[right=of a-2,anchor=b-1] (b) {bus=1}; ; this doesn't work because b isn't made in time for the position to be applied
    \draw (a-2) -- (b-1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185279/86 contains a few solutions to this problem.  Obviously, I'd recommend looking at the tikzmark one.

Comment: @AndrewStacey thanks for sharing, that is highly relevant. I've been using your `tikzmark` package as of recent anyhow, and the usage seems simple, so this might be a good solution. The scope key `adjust pic position` is not working for me though, do you know if your newest version has made its way to MiKTeX yet?

Comment: It's still in the development version, I need to test it some more (or find people willing to test it) before shipping it to ctan. Current version is at https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Positioning of `pic` can be tricky, however in your case relative positioning to nodes in `pic` works fine. In MWE below the code for `pic` is simplified and a bit reorganized:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, % new
                positioning}

\begin{document}

\def\busnodespace{3mm}
\tikzset{
pics/bus/.style ={
        code = { % 
            \foreach \i [count=\y from 0] in {1,...,#1} 
                {
                \node[inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=\busnodespace/2,
                      font=\scriptsize, text=red] (-n\i) at (0,\y*\busnodespace) {\i};
                }
            \scoped[on background layer] 
            \draw[ultra thick] (-n1.south) -- (-n#1.north);
}
        }}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic (a)                    {bus=3};  % bus of size 3
    \pic (b) [right=of a-n2]    {bus=1};  % bus of size 1 
    \draw[gray] (a-n2) -- (b-n1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic (a)                    {bus=3};  % bus of size 3
    \pic (b) [right=of a-n1]    {bus=2};  % bus of size 1
    \draw[gray] (a-n1) -- (b-n1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic (a)                    {bus=3};  % bus of size 3
    \pic (b) [right=of a-n3]    {bus=1};  % bus of size 1
    \draw[gray] (a-n3) -- (b-n1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
One more option. If you define anchor of ˙pic` with coordinate on the middle of it, than you can positioned second pic for example as:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 0mm and 15mm,
pics/bus/.style = {code = {\foreach \i [count=\y from 0] in {1,...,#1}
                           \node[inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=\busnodespace/2,
                                 font=\scriptsize, text=red] (-n\i) at (0,\y*\busnodespace) {\i};
                           \scoped[on background layer]
                           \draw[ultra thick] (-n1.south) -- coordinate (-@c) (-n#1.north);}}  % <---
                    ]
\def\busnodespace{3mm}
\pic (a)                    {bus=2}; 
\pic (b) [below right=3*\busnodespace and 15mm of a-@c]    {bus=3};  
\draw[gray] (a-n1) -- (b-n3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same result you will get with the following image body:

```
\pic (a)                    {bus=2};  
\pic (b) [right= of a-n1, yshift=-2*\busnodespace]    {bus=3}; 
\draw[gray] (a-n1) -- (b-n3);
```

Comment: Thanks--does @c have any special meaning or is it just a coord you made?

Comment: I'm also not seeing how the addendum code is different?

Comment: @likethevegetable, compare both examples and see differences, `@c` has not any special meaning, you can select different name.

Comment: I'm sorry but the code is identical, I think you made a copy+paste error

Comment: Ups, @likethevegetable, you are right! By mistake I overwrite original MWE with MWE in addendum. Corrected now.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I said previously that I would like to avoid calculation, but seeing as I have already defined busnodespace, it is a simple calculation. I will likely resort to something like `[right of = a-1, yshift=-1*\busnodespace] ` I was actually looking for an answer in the spirit of this question, and I think it contains the actual answer I'm looking for--however you provided a nice solution for my example.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185279/anchoring-tikz-pics

Comment: @likethevegetable, as I said in answer, positioning of `pic` is tricky. Your sintay for positioning (`right =f=...`) is deprecated. Use of` `yshift` is also valid approach.